# Drag and Drop issues with edge and 11

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

Hi I am trying to implement a drag and drop feature. The idea is that I need to drag and drop and image from the desktop to the drop area. I am very confused why this works perfectly fine with chrome. It does not want to work in Edge or 11. When I drag and drop the image it is either redirected. I am using asp freeloader.  I do not have much experience with front end so maybe its something simple i missing.

```
                <asp:FileUpload runat="server"
                class="fileupload-hidden-button"
                ClientIDMode="Static"
                ID="fileUpload"
                onchange="submitFile(this);" />
            <asp:Button runat="server"
                class="submitfile-hidden-button btn btn-sm"
                OnClick="SubmitFile_Click"
                ID="btnSubmit"
                Text="Load" />

            function callondrop(e) {

            e.stopPropagation();
            if ((e.dataTransfer && e.dataTransfer.files) || (e.dataTransfer && e.dataTransfer.files)) {
                var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
                console.log("callondrop files");
                submitFile(files[0]);


                $('#files')[0].files = files;
                $('#btnSubmit').click();
            }

            return false;
        }


            function submitFile(file) {
            if (!validate || CheckExtension(file)) {

                console.log(file);
                $("#btnSubmit").click();
                console.log("btn submitted");
            }
        };
```

I am also doing the image upload inside an iframe.

I included all the code I think could be relevant. I have tried following the HTML 5 tutorials but it seems that its using html 4 and I am unable to change that. any suggestions???

Comment: this *sounds* like it is entirely client-side, in which case the c# / asp.net tags might be misleading

Comment: @MarcGravell I have removed the C# thanks for the feedback